# React: How to solve Property 'children' is missing in type '{ }' but required in type 'Props'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two components - card and cardList and I want to call the cardList in the App component to show list of fetched data in cards.

But what I am missing is the connection between these two components to display the data correctly with passing the props.

This issue I am having is passing the carList component in the App.ts file with the correct props as parameter. someone can help please how to solve this issue?

Right now I have this error:

> Property 'children' is missing in type '{ pokemonItem: any; }' but required in type 'Props'.  TS2741

```
interface Props {
  pokemonItem: PokemonItem;
}

const CardComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const { pokemonItem } = props;
  const {
    name = '',
    weight = '',
    height = '',
    abilities = '',
    image,
  } = pokemonItem;
    
  return (
    <div>
      <div src={image} />
      <div>
        <h3>Name: {name}</h3>
        <h3>Height: {height}</h3>
        <h3>Weight: {weight}</h3>
        <h3>Abilities: {abilities}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The card list component

```
const API_URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20&offset=0';


interface Props {
  pokemonItem: PokemonItem;
}

export const CardListComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const { pokemonItem } = props;
  const {
    name = '',
    weight = '',
    height = '',
    abilities = '',
    image = '',
  } = pokemonItem;

  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState<PokemonItem[]>([]);
  const [loadItems, setLoadItems] = React.useState(API_URL);

  const getPokemons = async () => {
    const response: any = await fetch(loadItems);
    const data = await response.json();

    setLoadItems(data.next);
    setPokemon(data.results[0].name);
    
    const getEachPokemon = (result: any) => {
      result.forEach(async (element: any) => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https:pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${element.name}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        pokemon.push(data);
      });
    };

    getEachPokemon(data.results);
    await console.log(pokemon);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getPokemons();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {pokemon &&
        pokemon.map((item, index) => (
          <PokemonCard key={index} pokemonItem={item} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the app.ts file it shows error with the prop type. Not sure how to pass the pokemonItem props.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
      <div>
        <CardListComponent pokemonItem={PokemonItem} />
      </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how children are passed to react components.

children are the elements that'd be inside of your

```
<PokemonCard props={props}>
{children}
</PokemonCard>
```

In your case it seems like you don't need children there at all. It's better to not use

```
component: FC<Props> = () => ....
```

Since FC takes children as default, better use

```
component = (props: Props) => ....
```

And put in Props interface everything that you need, and nothing more, eg.:

```
interface Props {
  pokemonItem: PokemonItem;
}

const CardComponent = (props: Props) => ...
```

If you'd ever want to take children you can use FC as you did, but properly or just add children as you did to your interface props and no need for: `FC<Props>` then.

Comment: thanks. But in the case of my error what would be your suggest? Also what changes do I need for the CardListComponent and how the props should be passed to the App.ts, where CardListComponent is being called.